# How to finish this proof: invertibility and zero divisorness in $C(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I tried to prove the following and was wondering if someone could please help me finish my proof:

Let $\Omega $ be compact Hausdorff. Then $f \in C(\Omega)$ is a left topological zero divisor if and only if $f$ is not invertible.

Assumptions and definitions: the functions are functions into $\mathbb C$ and the norm is the $\sup$ norm. A (left) topological zero divisor in a Banach algebra is an element $a$ such that there exist $a_n \in A$ with $\|a_n\|=1$ and $aa_n \to 0$.

My proof idea: The direction $\implies$ caused no problems so I will omit it. We want to show that if $f$ is not invertible then it is a topological zero divisor. The map $f$ is not invertible if and only if  $f(\omega ) = 0$ for some $\omega \in \Omega$. We use this to construct a sequence $f_n$ with $\|f_n\|=1$ and $ff_n \to 0$. Note that since $f$ is continuous, $O_n = f^{-1}(B(0,{1\over n} \setminus \{0\})$ is open.

We apply Urysohn's lemma to get a continuous function $g_n: \Omega \to [0,1]$ such that $g_n(\omega) = 1$ and $g_n(O_n^c) = 0$. Let $f_n = {g_n \over \|g_n\|_\infty}$. Then $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$ and $ff_n \to 0 $ pointwise.

Now I need an argument why this convergence is in fact uniform. How to do this?

Comment: Pick $x\in \Omega$. Either $x\in O_n$, in which case ... because $f_n(x)$ and $f(x)$ ..., or $x\notin O_n$, in which case ... because $f_n(x)$ ...

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. Yes. The case I am struggling with is $x \in O_n$. Of course if $x \in O_n^c$ then $f_n(x) = 0$ by definition. If you don't mind please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: The other thing that troubled me was that $\lim f_n$ was not in the space but then that's not required by the definition of zero divisor.

Comment: Right, and in general, the sequence $f_n$ cannot have a limit in the space, otherwise $f$ would have to be a true zero divisor, not only a topological one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is a case distinction.

If $x\notin O_n$, then by construction of the $f_n$ you know that $f(x)f_n(x) = 0$. And if $x \in O_n$, then you know something about $f(x)$ that, together with $\lVert f_n\rVert_\infty = 1$ gives you $\lVert f\cdot f_n\rVert_\infty \leqslant \varepsilon_n$ for a monotonic sequence $\varepsilon_n \searrow 0$.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't see: $f$ is bounded because it is continuous. The $\sup$ of the $f_n$ is actually attained in $O_n$. Furthermore, $\|ff_n\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty$. What else do I know?

Comment: By the definition of $O_n$, what do you know about $f(x)$?

Comment: *facepalm*. I know that $|f| \le {1 \over n}$ on $O_n$. Thank you for your patience.